# How to create full window canvas with meteor?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, meteor

How to create a full window canvas with meteor?

I am fairly new with the HTML5 canvas element, after different tutorials and some trying i can do all basic stuff, but i am struggeling with this full window problem for some hours now and wasn't able to find a solution.

With following code

```
Template.canvasT.rendered = function(){
    var canvas = $("#canvas");
    canvas.css('width', $(window).innerWidth());
    canvas.css('height', $(window).innerHeight());
    ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d');

    ; some drawing
}
```

a zoom effect is created, how to do it without? Thanks.

Code for full window canvas from:
[Meteor: How to Get Context of an HTML5 Canvas Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25694020/meteor-how-to-get-context-of-an-html5-canvas-element/25694084#25694084)

[MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/S9Wr4k7uhppKRKLPn/Copy%20of%20Meteor%20Canvas) with the full code and the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*After an other answer pointed me in the right direction, i finally figured it out myself.*

Set the html tag attributes **and** the css style attributes:

```
Template.canvasT.rendered = function(){
    var canvas = $("#canvas");
    canvas.attr('width',$(window).innerWidth());
    canvas.attr('height',$(window).innerHeight());

    canvas.css('width',$(window).innerWidth() + "px");
    canvas.css('height',$(window).innerHeight() + "px");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is has a zoom effect is because you are manipulating the canvas element's CSS properties instead of its width and height attributes.

Try:

```
DTemplate.canvasT.rendered = function(){
    var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
    canvas.width = $(window).innerWidth();
    canvas.height = $(window).innerHeight();
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ; some drawing
}
```

Comment: This has no effect. It does not resize the canvas at all.